# How do I login with external Facebook login to ASP.NET Core 7

Tags: facebook, asp.net-core, authentication

I'm developing my hobby project and I want to log in with 3rd party authentication. Google and Microsoft drivers are working well, but I can not log in with Facebook. I've configured the driver - Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook 7.0.5  - according to the documentation, I get a non too talkative error message:

Sorry, something went wrong.
We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.

I couldn't find any error in the server log, the redirect is working well to the Facebook site, but Facebook returns an error 500 with zero details.

How can I step forward? What I should do to resolve this issue? How can I get detailed errors to solve this problem? Does anyone have any ideas?

Relevant code in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddFacebook(options =>
    {
        IConfigurationSection FBAuthNSection =
        config.GetSection("Authentication:Facebook");
        options.AppId = FBAuthNSection["AppId"];
        options.AppSecret = FBAuthNSection["AppSecret"];
        options.SaveTokens = true;
    })
```

Relevant log message:

```
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook.FacebookHandler[1]
      HandleChallenge with Location: https://www.facebook.com/v11.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=965797767788109&scope=email&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A7098%2Fsignin-facebook&state=CfDJ8Ju3hI8HPyJEpgxrMf7GKJSGPqfbEv7RCZb0ENF64GsyO52GFjOQvjPTwar6Uyyfn0WtlLga7V803jjugEArC0Z-3SxxCjgTJyL-fuUGfXWArAS_fpkHWVMewglB_Jdd6R7evXHXmPb-jGjQIHvMDbduuSfcig_-oSXBEpGimXnFj2qoMCS7IjYTEK_FSFAuxxmFdYub3J7RZpdV0DcOzP6o7i-GAN9nx1L770kwOCNWrroqasKHEKaaeqCB61Urmj89_PukzlSJMYXdpWDBs60xJMQXxatGHHkCP3_-FO4H; and Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Correlation.Yr_iyns3N0RfsyagBixoWWRjOiV3c7yrJhECWoJBndE=N; expires=Tue, 06 Jun 2023 15:47:38 GMT; path=/signin-facebook; secure; samesite=none; httponly.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook.FacebookHandler[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: Facebook was challenged.
```

I tried to trace Nuget package with the following appsettings:

```
{
  "DetailedErrors": true,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook": "Trace"
    }
  }
}
```

I've reviewed the Facebook application settings repeatedly and couldn't resolve this issue.

Comment: do you have MVC or WEB API project?

Comment: Almost MVC, I uses server side blazor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might need to re-visit your Facebook setup to allow your application to read person's primary email address (*Not enabled by default as of 2023-07-25*).

- Visit https://developers.facebook.com
- Navigate to your application (via `My Apps`)
- Click on `Use cases` (drill down by pressing `>`)
- Click `Edit` for `Authentication and account creation`
- Click `Add` for `email` (The email permission allows your app to read a person's primary email address)

*Hope this helps someone (:*

Answer (score 0):

Try to add  Event handlers and study it. In API project doesn't work without forced redirect (see OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint). Also in my experience, it doesn't work when using Swagger UI to call(maybe Blazor behavior is the same). Only direct links without Swagger work. Maybe it will help you

```
 .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
            {
                facebookOptions.AppId = configuration["FacebookSettings:AppId"];
                facebookOptions.AppSecret = configuration["FacebookSettings:AppSecret"];
                facebookOptions.CallbackPath = "/callback/facebook";
                facebookOptions.SaveTokens = true;
                facebookOptions.Events.OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = (redirectContext) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(redirectContext.RedirectUri);
                    redirectContext.Response.Redirect(redirectContext.RedirectUri);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
                facebookOptions.Events.OnTicketReceived = (context) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(context.HttpContext.User);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
                facebookOptions.Events.OnCreatingTicket = (context) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(context.Identity);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
                facebookOptions.Events.OnAccessDenied = (context) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(context.HttpContext.User);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };

            })
```